# Running node-red-start after trying to create HTTPS "Error 140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small"

Tags: ssl, https, raspberry-pi3, node-red

Hi everybody I have been setting up remote access to node-red for my raspberry Pi. I have amended the settings.js and installed node-red-admin but when I go to start node-red I get the following error:

```
Error: error:140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:131:17)
at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:1152:27)
at Server (_tls_wrap.js:1030:8)
at new Server (https.js:65:14)
at Object.createServer (https.js:89:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js:141:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:12) {
library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate',
  reason: 'ee key too small',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL'
}
nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
nodered.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
nodered.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool.
_tls_common.js:131
  c.context.setCert(cert);
```

This happened after I successfully created privatekey.pem and certificate.pem. To create these files I used:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
```

then used

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out private-csr.pem
```

after which I put in relevant info and then recieved verification "signature is ok" with

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in private-csr.pem -signkey privatekey.pem -out certificate.pem
```

As the above returned privatekey.pem and certificate.pem files under ls -la I moved onto uncommented the following:

```
// The `https` setting requires the `fs` module. Uncomment the 
following
// to make it available:
var fs = require("fs");
module.exports = {
// the tcp port that the Node-RED web server is listening on
uiPort: process.env.PORT || 1880,
```

and also

```
adminAuth: {
type: "credentials",
users: [
    {
username: "admin",
password: "$2a$08$9Miva2AQEFlXQ3S7emXlIuLkLzNzi9yzgqxGYMY5dzK4FzNQa7dCu",
permissions: "*" 
    }
]
},
```

with loading fs module

```
https: {
key: fs.readFileSync('/home/pi/.node-red/privatekey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/pi/.node-red/certificate.pem')
},
```

After doing this configuration I get the error message stated at the beginning. 
Update: I did delete the contents of .node-red/settings.js and replaced with https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/node-red/settings.js
and node-red starts! woohoo!
However when try to reconfigure the settings.js file again it runs into the same error.. 
FYI I am carefully uncommenting lines however could the problem reside in the hash-pw i receive from node-red-admin? Because when I try to install node-red-admin with "npm install -g node-red-admin" after logging in as root via "su" it comes up with the following:

```
pi@padrejuan:~ $ su
Password: 
root@padrejuan:/home/pi# npm install -g node-red-admin
/usr/local/bin/node-red-admin -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red- 
admin/node-red-admin.js

> bcrypt@3.0.6 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red- 
admin/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.6 
and node@12.11.1 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile 
with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red-admin/node_modules/bcrypt/lib' 
gyp WARN EACCES user "nobody" does not have permission to access the 
dev dir "/root/.cache/node-gyp/12.11.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red-admin/node_modules/bcrypt/.node- 
gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
```

and so on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that the latest versions of openssl now considers keys with a bit length of 1024 to be insecure.

Re-generate the private key with a size of 2048 and then recreate the certificate.

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/126#issuecomment-505933083

```
It is just a matter of editing file /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf changing last line
from:
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
to
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Comment: Do not make this change unless you full understand how it degrades the security of your whole system

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RHEL 8 & above, these are the steps to resolve:

```
update-crypto-policies --show

update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT

reboot
```

Comment: Again much better to create a new stronger private key than degrade the security of your whole system